# Accessing Textbox Value Using Inserted JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, textbox

I'm Having a bit of an issue. I'm using JavaScript to inset HTML into a webpage along with an event handler for the onblur event. It looks like this:

```
return '<input id = "txtIn" type="text" value=" ' + dateTime + '" onblur= "submitManualDate(document.getElementById("txIn").value(), 2, 3);" />';
```

I'm getting a syntax error. However, the following works perfectly fine:

```
return '<input id = "txtIn" type="text" value=" ' + dateTime + '" onblur= "submitManualDate(1, 2, 3);" />';
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: How about passing `this` as a function argument ? `"` inside `"` expression will break the string..

Comment: Can you post the description of the syntax error?

Comment: That prevented the syntax error. But how will I access the value in the function after the fact?

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById("txIn").value` not `document.getElementById("txIn").value()`. Also note if there are multiple elements with same `id` then it will always return the value of first element having `id='txIn'`

Comment: I was getting a syntax error with that one as well. The method below using "this" seemed to have worked. Thank you for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `"` inside `"`(double quoted) expression will break the `string`.

> It's better to pass `this` as an argument as you should not have multiple elements with same `id` attributes in a document.

Try this example:

```js
(function() {
  var input = '<input type="text" value="5" onblur= "submitManualDate(this, 2, 3);" />';
  document.getElementById('parent').innerHTML = input;
})();

function submitManualDate(elem, j, k) {
  alert(elem.value + ' ' + j + ' ' + k);
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'></div>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/cL6572o9/)